# Does the EU fund you only if you legally agree not to damage the EU's reputation in any way?

Tags: politics, europe

In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7GazJsyWw8) shows clips of [Jacob Rees-Mogg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Rees-Mogg).

[At 6:55](https://youtu.be/h7GazJsyWw8?t=415), he is shown hosting 
an [LBC](https://www.lbc.co.uk/) talkback show, talking about EU funding. He claims:

> You don't get money from the EU unless you sign up to a contract saying that you won't do anything that damages the reputation of the EU.

Is that true?

Comment: Do you have a version of this incident that isn't from a highly edited highlight video?

Comment: This would be better asked on Politics.

Comment: Sounds like it would be a fairly common caveat for most funding agencies...

Comment: @DJClayworth I believe OP originally posted this on Politics.SE and was redirected here.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly common stipulation. Is it supposed to be controversial?

Comment: @dont_shog_me_bro the difference here is whether or not this is mandated formally via a contract or just implied/expected.

Comment: @Leon still don't see it. Not bringing the source of funding into disrepute is a pretty standard part of any contract to receive funding.

Comment: @DJClayworth: no, it was closed there already. Not enough politics in it, apparently.

Comment: The EU pays a lot of different people money. It's very unclear which of those transaction should be counted as funding and unless this question gets more precise I vote to close it here.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the speaker meant, but Article 3 (5) of the Maastricht Treaty is "5. In its relations with the wider world, the Union shall uphold and promote its values and interests and contribute to the protection of its citizens. ". You can hardly uphold and promote the values of the Union if you damage its reputation. You could also argue Article 4 (3) is applicable as well as Article 21. Without more information, it will be hard to pinpoint exactly what the speaker meant.